# 2018 January Challenge: Prove inequality in geometry problem

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, euclidean-geometry, recreational-mathematics, geometric-inequalities

Considering it's the beginning of a new year, I have created the following challenge. I hope to make one every month until December 2018!

Here goes:

> [image]
>
> Show that $AD-AB>AC^3$. Do not use scale drawings.

Comment: Is the line $AD$ not drawn?

Comment: Do you mean $BC=\sqrt2-1$?

Comment: @Alec Please see edit

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg Yes $BC$ is equal to $\sqrt2 - 1$.

Comment: As interesting as the problem may be, this site isn't really the best place for it. (I'll note that we have a `puzzle` tag, but it admonishes: *If the answer is known to you, please do not use this tag to "riddle" other users, but rather to ask about the correctness of a possible solution or ways to extend and improve an existing solution.*) You might consider the [Puzzling Stack Exchange](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com) or the [Art of Problem Solving](http://artofproblemsolving.com) forums. Or, even better: start your own math challenge blog!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We need to prove that
$$\sqrt{1-\frac{1}{\sqrt2}}-\sqrt{\frac{3}{2}}(\sqrt2-1)>\left(1-\frac{1}{\sqrt2}\right)^3,$$ which is true.

Indeed, let $DFMK$ be the given rectangle,

$\Delta FBM$ be given triangle ($FM=BM=1$,$\measuredangle FMB=90^{\circ}$)  and

$\Delta EFC$ be another given triangle ($EF=FC=1$, $\measuredangle EFC=90^{\circ}$).

Thus, $$\frac{AC}{EF}=\frac{BC}{BF}$$ or
$$\frac{AC}{1}=\frac{\sqrt2-1}{\sqrt2},$$ which gives 
$$AC=1-\frac{1}{\sqrt2}.$$
Hence,
$$AB=\sqrt{AC^2+BC^2}=\sqrt{\left(1-\frac{1}{\sqrt2}\right)^2+(\sqrt2-1)^2}=\sqrt{\frac{3}{2}}(\sqrt2-1).$$
Now, since $\measuredangle DCA=45^{\circ}$, by law of cosines for $\Delta DAC$ we obtain:
$$\begin{align}AD&=\sqrt{\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt2}\right)^2+\left(1-\frac{1}{\sqrt2}\right)^2-2\cdot\frac{1}{\sqrt2}\cdot\left(1-\frac{1}{\sqrt2}\right)\cdot\frac{1}{\sqrt2}}\\&=\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}+\frac{3}{2}-\sqrt2-1+\frac{1}{\sqrt2}}=\sqrt{1-\frac{1}{\sqrt2}}.\end{align}$$

Comment: No. I used Pythagoras and the law of cosines for $\Delta DAC$.

Comment: No it's not $90^o$

Comment: I added something. See now.